# arrow in function name in Clojure

Tags: clojure

For the code below, is the arrow a macro or just simple character in the function name? ( from [here](http://clojure-doc.org/articles/tutorials/parsing_xml_with_zippers.html))

```
(defn file->map
  [file]
  ;; TODO
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The arrow is part of the function name. There is a function definition, isn't?

```
(defn file->map  [file]
  ;; TODO)
```

(defn) defines a function. In your REPL, type:

```
(doc defn) 

(source defn)
```

Even Clojure core code provides such names, such as cond->> , cond-> , as-> ,  some->>

Comment: thanks. I did not expect arrow is legal as part of the function name.

Comment: The `>` character is not currently listed as safe to use in symbols at http://clojure.org/reader, but odds seem good that it will continue to be so as the combination `->` is prevalent.

Comment: @A.Webb Clojure uses them actually. Such as cond->> , cond-> , as-> , some->>

Comment: Of course, and it seems unlikely that the reader would be complicated in the future to provide exceptions for these core functions. However, note these are all in the tail, and there are some characters which are currently accepted in some positions but not others in symbols, e.g. `#`, `:`.

Comment: @A.Webb: There are also the functions generated by defrecord: `->Foo` and `map->Foo`. So it seems to me like an oversight that the character hasn't been explicitly allowed yet, because Clojure itself uses the symbol all over the place. Maybe they're considering XML literals and want to outlaw it after a `<` or something, but arrows are clearly valid at the beginning, middle and end of symbols.

Comment: @Chuck This is true, but the mechanism there is the same that allows you to create `#'user/bar:` through `(eval \`(def ~(symbol "bar:") 1))` when `(def bar: 1)` is invalid. There may be other examples, and I'm sure it is probably fine, but I don't know if we have an official ruling.

Comment: @Chuck Never mind, that's a great example. If you broke arrows in the middle of names `defrecord` would still work as is but you'd wind up making it a nuisance to actually _use_ `map->Foo` after it is created.